# Get an enum value in String format

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get my enum value in string format

```
export enum Roles {
    manager = "manager",
    user = "user"
}

console.log(" Roles.manager: ", Roles[Roles.manager]);
```

This is the result in the console:

```
Roles.manager:  manager
```

What do I need to change for him to present it to me in String format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the `Roles.manager:` because you are logging it, try running the following.

```
enum Roles {
  manager = "manager",
  user = "user"
}

console.log(Roles.manager); // this
console.log(Roles[Roles.manager]); // not this

console.log(typeof(Roles.manager)); // string 
console.log(isString(Roles.manager)); // true

function isString(x: string) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object String]"
}
```

Looking at this in JS might show better how you can access the values

```
"use strict";
var Roles;
(function (Roles) {
    Roles["manager"] = "manager";
    Roles["user"] = "user";
})(Roles || (Roles = {}));
```

Comment: Can you also add some explanation as to why removing `export` works?